# Can Oracle run Windows command line functions?

Tags: oracle, cmd

Something similar to the way MSSQL uses xp_commandshell ?
Would make it things much easier if I were able to get directory info, parse log files, and run queries without needing to batch it all first.

Comment: You do know there a *very* severe warning *against* using xp_cmdshell? In fact, you have to disable quite a few security features to get it to run? You definitely don't need it in SQL Server - if you want to run jobs, use SQL Server Agent. You don't need it in Oracle either

Comment: As for directories, parsing, and running queries in SQL Server, you have SSIS. Not xp_cmdshell. If you want to write your own scripts, use the Agent

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, You mean SSMS

Comment: @WEI_DBA no, I mean SQL Server Agent. If you want to run a job, you put it in SQL Server Agent and schedule it. You don't run shell scripts. PS: I'm downloading and parsing files from multiple banks, airlines and IATA this way, importing it in SQL Server and checking for differences.

Comment: Very good. Thanks for the clarification. OP may want to look at Powershell as well.

Comment: @WEI_DBA as long ast it's executed *outside* the database, eg through SQL Server Agent. Running external scripts from inside the database is just as bad, no matter the *shell* you use

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Agreed!

Comment: Only using xp_commandshell as a reference.  We switched from MSSQL to Oracle a few years ago. I was never aware of any security features being disabled then.  I need this for on-demand / production issues on 5k+ servers that I access on a per need basis so a scheduled job is not going to work.

Comment: An example would be checking if certain table information exists or is correct while at the same checking if directories contain needed files and their timestamps  that should have updated the DB with the data

Comment: If it's about Oracle, why put SQL Server tag?

Comment: That was not intentional. Should be removed

Comment: Please clarify if you want to run the executable **on the database server** (which is what `xp_cmdshell` does) or if you just want to run some executable **locally** where your SQL client (i.e. Oracle SQL Developer) is running. Those are two **very** different things.

Comment: I need to run it on a remote machine preferably from SQL Developer connected to remote server and placed in-line with regular queries and run together giving a single output.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> An example would be checking if certain table information exists or is correct while at the same checking if directories contain needed files and their timestamps that should have updated the DB with the data

If you just want to read/write files, [UTL_FILE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70915) can check if files exist and access their contents. External tables will also let you access system files. I would recommend doing this, and making sure that your automated shell scripts are putting any data you need to access (e.g. timestamps) into a file of some kind.

If you absolutely *must* run arbitrary code on your server, the only way I know of doing it is to use a Java application in the database. [Here's the relevant section of the Oracle documentation on doing that](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chten.htm#JJDEV13638).

Edit: I forgot about external DBMS_SCHEDULER jobs, as @Martin Berger mentioned. It's a little convoluted, but I think if you want to do something more complicated than reading files, this is probably the easiest solution. [Here's a nice example of running 'ls' and getting the output](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN12392).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a **Oracle Scheduler Agent** to run jobs outside of the Instance. You can run the Scheduler Agent on any node, it's not limited to the hosts of the database itself. Please see the documentation: [Using the Oracle Scheduler Agent to Run Remote Jobs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADMIN/administering-oracle-scheduler.htm#ADMIN12048).
To run a script or executable on the host of the database, use

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(job_name => ...,
                              job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
                              job_action => '...',
   )
```

- [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ARPLS/DBMS_SCHEDULER.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.

SQL Developer implements most (though not all) of the SQL*Plus functionality.

In SQL*Plus, as well as in SQL Developer, the command to run OS commands is HOST.

If I enter this in the code editor (SQL Developer):

```
host dir c:\app
```

the output shown in the Script Output pane is this:

```
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is A28B-485D

 Directory of c:\app

06/19/2017  01:23 PM    <DIR>          .
06/19/2017  01:23 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/10/2016  08:48 AM            10,244 .DS_Store
11/10/2016  08:48 AM    <DIR>          intro
06/19/2017  03:29 PM    <DIR>          sandbox
               1 File(s)         10,244 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  876,968,189,952 bytes free
```

Obviously, there will be limitations. Some OS commands can't be run from within SQL Developer; and for others, you will need to check permissions.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping/looking for.

Comment: @NoodlesPokerandSportsMedia: that is something **entirely** different then `xp_cmdshell` which runs an executable **on the server** not on the client

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I am handicapped here since everything for me runs on the same computer. I assume in a networked environment, if the client and server are on the same network, the "client" OS commands can access the file system on the server, as long as the proper setup and permissions are in place? Otherwise, I believe UTL_FILE works (primarily) on the server - is that closer to whatever `xp_cmdshell` is? (With which I am not familiar.)

Comment: @mathguy: no: the client can not access files on the database server (unless you e.g. have a network _share_ accessible to all computers on the network). And "accessing files" again is something completely then (remotely) starting an executable on the server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I assume (again, can't test on my setup) that SQL script files and such reside on the client, and are "executed" from the client end. I am not familiar with situations where one might want to execute programs on the server from their SQL Developer interface. Perhaps I should let others with more experience discuss this...

Comment: @mathguy: but that's **exactly** what `xp_cmdshell` does.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up.  Was getting confused by the results running Host Dir.  This produces a directory from the Citrix  server my tools are on and not the remote server I need.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `HOST` command is just like (to a great degree) having a command shell available. Keep in mind that if it is running on Windows, it is a `cmd.exe` command line. As mathguy shows, you can use `dir C:\app` to get a directory listing.

If it is running on Linux/UNIX, it will be ksh/bash or some other flavor where the `ls` command will produce a directory listing.

More complex commands can be used. I wasted a good bit of time trying to figure out how to get Oracle commands to detect the presence of a file and delete it. It is simple with the `HOST` command.

```
HOST IF EXIST thespoolfile.txt (DEL thespoolfile.txt)
```

Actually, I prefer to pass the name of the spool file in as a parameter and use:

```
HOST IF EXIST &1 (DEL &1)
SPOOL &1
```