# Run windows cmd command from sqlplus

Tags: windows, cmd, sqlplus

I am from linux background and new to windows. I have installed oracle database in windows. I use sqlplus to connect to the oracle database from cmd. In linux , we can use exclamatory '!' to type shell commands from sqlplus. Is there any way to run cmd commands from sqlplus in windows ?

**Command:**

**In windows:**

```
SQL> !dir
SP2-0042: unknown command "!dir" - rest of line ignored.
```

**In linux:**

```
SQL> !echo $ORACLE_SID
orcl
```

Comment: Are you able to use the `HOST` command? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46980852/447901

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> host dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows

 Directory of C:\Users\oracle\src

06/17/2022  06:31 AM    <DIR>          .
06/17/2022  06:31 AM    <DIR>          ..
```

as in https://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/97495/

> $dir

> host dir

both may work